# Query Validation Rules associated with an Object using REST API

Tags: rest-api, rest

I need to retrieve all the validation rules associated with a given object, using the REST API.

Looking in doc/forums, I've found that I could retrieve validation rules associated with an object using the following query:

https:///services/data/v35.0/tooling/query?q=Select Id,Active,Description,ErrorDisplayField, ErrorMessage From ValidationRule Where EntityDefinitionId = 'xxxxx'

The problem is that I don't have the object'ID needed to filter, I only have its name. Is there any way to filter using the object's name?

Another alternative seems to be getting the object'ID, but it seems that Metadata REST API (i.e. describe) does not return it.

Any help on this is very appreciated.

Mariana

Comment: Does the API allow you to use the EntryDefinition object? If so you could do something like "WHERE EntryDefinition.FullName = 'Account'". The doc for the object is at (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_entitydefinition.htm#topic-title)

Answer (score 1):

Please use the below solution in workbench via REST explorer & method as "GET".

/services/data/v43.0/tooling/query?q=Select+Id,Active,Description,EntityDefinition.DeveloperName,ErrorConditionFormula,+ErrorMessage+From+ValidationRule+where+EntityDefinition.DeveloperName+=+'Lead'

Thanks!

Comment: ErrorConditionFormula is not a field available on the ValidationRule object. My guess is you'll have to individually query validation rules and then use the ErrorConditionFormula field from the associated metadata